# Problems installing Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, nokogiri, bundle

I'm following [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) and I've come to where I need to install these gems:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.3'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.0.1' 
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end
```

Then I do a:

```
bundle install
```

But terminal gives me this:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.3) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.3) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.2) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.14) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.26) 
Using actionpack (3.0.3) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.9) 
Using mail (2.2.16) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.3) 
Using arel (2.0.9) 
Using activerecord (3.0.3) 
Using activeresource (3.0.3) 
Using bundler (1.0.12) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.2) 
Installing nokogiri (1.4.4) /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:574:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/.autotest (Errno::EACCES)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:574:in `open'
```

I've done a bunch of research on this and I've found some people who had the same problems:
http://taleswithrails.com/2011/01/error-gemfile-could-not-find-gem-webrat/

And I've read the installation guide: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

But I can't get:

```
sudo port ...
```

or

```
sudo apt-get ...
```

To work. They return with "command not found". So I think I have two issues here...

1) Nokogiri is not installing properly and I'm not sure why. I also don't know what "flavor" of machine I'm running (in other words, which of the Nokogiri installation instructions pertains to my setup).

2) Those commands don't work on my system (OSX 10.6) and I'm not sure why. I've read up on Macports and libxml2 but it's a little unclear to me what it is and what I need to do (or if it's even applicable to me). I did try installing macports, but I don't have Xcode, which is required. But I'm not a "mac developer". Is this my only option?

Comment: " I don't have Xcode, which is required. But I'm not a "mac developer". Is this my only option?". It is not your only option, but it is your best option. Apple bundles all the tools needed to compile and install Ruby and gems into XCode. You could take a long time and build up the needed parts, and, over time keep adding things, or just bite the bullet and let XCode load it all. XCode is big but it works fine and saves you the trouble.

Comment: Be careful following directions found on websites on how to install things on your Mac. There is a lot of old, stale, or wrong information, or information that is great but for a narrow audience of experienced sysadmin-types. We often see requests for help here on SO for people who didn't know what they were doing and got painted into a corner. Especially, do NOT try upgrading your Apple-installed Ruby, and do NOT use sudo with RVM or anything it installs for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like you have several different problems going on at the same time and you need to sort them out one by one.

First, can you run `gem install Nokogiri` in your terminal, and then try using it in IRB to check that it works?

Then, you should that `sudo apt-get` is the command for getting software using aptitude which you will NOT be using on your mac, it is used for Linux. and `sudo port` uses `macports` to install nokogiri, which will only work if you have Macports installed.

I would recommend [getting Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) and using `brew install nokogiri`

once you have it working locally in a ruby script, then worry about rails.

The permission denied error is probably because you have been using some sudo's where you should not be, on a mac you really should never be using that command. If you need to install ruby gems, look into RVM which will let you install 'most' gems without needing to sudo

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks so much for taking the time to respond! When I run `gem install nokogiri`, tells me permission denied. Thank you for clarifying on the apt-get. What are your thoughts on macports? Im going to give homebrew a shot right now and will check back.

Comment: Hi Paul, I've installed homebrew and I'm told to DL xcode, which I'm doing. Seems to be taking a while, it must be big. So will I now use brew instead of gem when installing gems? Also, I'm trying to get RVM, but `bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)` (which is how I'm supposed to install it) gives me: `-bash: $: command not found` ... any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: NVM, I was able to get RVM running. Thx.

Comment: @paul-kaplan Installed Xcode and followed the Nokokiri installation instructions — bam. Thank you so much. I appreciate it more than you know.